# replace default Maven lifecycle goals

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-2

When I run `mvn deploy` in my project which has `<packaging>war</packaging>` I get the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project store-service-impl: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter

It appears that by default, the `deploy:deploy` goal is bound to the `deploy` lifecycle phase. In other words, Maven will try to deploy the generated artefact (a .war file in this case) to a remote repository when the `deploy` lifecycle phase is run.

In my case, I want to deploy the war to a remote Tomcat instance rather than a remote Maven repository. I've added the following to the `pom.xml`

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                    <type>remote</type>
                </container>
                <!--
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-tomcat</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                -->
                <configuration>
                    <type>runtime</type>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.remote.uri>http://10.60.60.60:8080/manager</cargo.remote.uri>
                        <cargo.remote.username>jack</cargo.remote.username>
                        <cargo.remote.password>secret</cargo.remote.password>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <deployer>
                    <type>remote</type>
                </deployer>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This successfully deploys the .war when I run `mvn cargo:deploy`. However, if I then bind this goal to the `deploy` phase of the Maven lifecycle by uncommenting the `<executions>` element, I get the aforementioned error.

It seems that the `cargo:deploy` goal has been added to the goals bound to the `deploy` phase, but  I want to **replace** the `deploy:deploy` goal that is bound to the `deploy` lifecycle phase (by default) with the `cargo:deploy` goal, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should bind cargo to `pre-integration-test` instead of `deploy` - then your failsafe tests can run against the deployed war file during the `integration-test` phase. You would run the tests using `mvn verify`.

Comment: I don't have any integration tests, so this isn't relevant to me. If I bind cargo to the `pre-integration-test` phase, then the .war will be deployed when someone runs `mvn install`. I only want it to be deployed when someone runs `mvn deploy`.

Comment: No offence, but IMHO you're mis-using the `deploy` phase. It has the same name as what you want to do but it's not what you want. It's for deploying to a maven repository. `mvn install` installs the war file to the local computer's maven repository as I'm sure you know. I would investigate using something like Jenkins to deploy to a remote server on a successful build. Oh, and get some integration tests ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try disabling the deploy plugin before configuring cargo:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable default deploy goal with maven-deploy-plugin on execution id default-deploy. Old thread, I put it here in case for someone.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```